# Invalid multibyte sequence in argument ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/debug.php

Tags: kohana

Добрый день. Я начинающий в работе на php, у меня такой вопрос: есть сайт сделанный с помощью kohana, нужно создать ещё один сайт идентичный существующему (просто с другим направлением товаров). Старый спйт лежит на hosting.ua, на том же хостинге зарегистрировали новый аккаунт и домен нового сайта. Скопировал туда старую базу данных и закачал файлы сайта на ftp,  указал данные в database.php.

При входе на сайт выдаёт такую ошибку:
ErrorException [ 2 ]: htmlspecialchars(): Invalid multibyte sequence in argument ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/debug.php [ 311 ]

Подскажите плз что я упустил или не доделал, или как это исправить...

Answer (score 1):

Поднимался уже данный вопрос тут. Недели 2 назад, можете поискать.
А так, вот ссылка, вероятно это поможет [Ссылка](http://blog-tree.com/2011/12/yii-htmlspecialchars/)